# Django form validation fails when using second unmanged database / How to use 2nd DB for form validation?

Tags: django, database, django-forms

I am using two databases in my django project:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
    "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
},
"2ndDB": {
    "ENGINE": "sql_server.pyodbc",
    "NAME": "2nddb-sqldb",
    "USER": CRED["user"],
    "PASSWORD": CRED["password"],
    "HOST": "2ndserver-sqlsrv.database.windows.net",
    "PORT": 1433,
    "OPTIONS": {"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",},
},
```

In my view I try to validate my form:

views.py

```
def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, user=request.user.get_username())
        if form.is_valid():
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = "post"
        self.helper.add_input(Submit("submit", "OK"))

    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = (
            "uuid",
            "xyz",
        )
```

Which fails as it tries to validate the unique constraint of the pk of the model in the unmanaged db:

models.py

```
class Registration(models.Model):

uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="UUID")

class Meta:
    db_table = "xyz"
    managed = False
```

It is pretty that it tries to access the primary db an obviously can not find the tabel. (Which is the error that I receive.) I know how to use the second DB when saving the form or making queries by using the "using" option. I can't figure out how to make this work with the validation though.

Comment: How did you setup your table routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread you're question. What you are looking for is a database router: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing

You configure these to route some requests to your second database. You could use the router show in the django docs but instead of `route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes'}` you would use: `route_app_labels = {'yourapp', 'registration'}` (and change the relevant reference to your DB too).

Comment: Cheers, I was just reading about the automatic routing again after reading your question. I will give this a try. 
Was thinking I could to something like this:

object = Registration.objects.using("datadictionary").get(uuid=uuid)
    form = ConfirmForm(
        instance=object, connstring=request.session["conn_string"]
    )

For the form as well, but maybe that just not the way to do it.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Apparently the "using" approach wasn't very sensible at all.